# How to set text that has colors for functions in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python .Just installed 3.6.3. I browse through some tutorials, they have like numbers indicating which line is the code. and also, For variables/ command functions like print. it is in certain color

Comment: Do you mean syntax highlighting? And line numbers?

Comment: I think that is more of a terminal question than a python question.

Comment: When I run Python.exe, it appears to be like a Command prompt . everything is in black and white. Yeah, should be syntax highlighting. May I know how to set it?

Comment: You are using the Python terminal, not its IDE (IDLE) - Use the Python IDLE or download you own IDE. Arunav says Sumblime3, I say Pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ - Also note, Python terminal and a Python IDE are two DIFFERENT things.

Comment: May I know why do i type something like Print(30) on Python terminal, it returns me 30, While on sublime text, it doesn't returns me any results?

Comment: Terminals are basically, giving the computer code and it executing it straight away. You told pythons terminal to do `Print(30)`. And it will do that straight away. IDEs / python files, are scripts which you store the commands in one location, and when you are ready to use the script you run the file. So lets say you put `Print(30)` inside `test.py` you would need to execute the file. So within the cmd `python test.py` which would then display `30`. You should really look up the basics of python before you do anything else...

Comment: Thank you Goralight! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is syntax colouring. This comes with most text editors, but maybe not with the current one you are using. I recommend Sublime Text 3 as a good IDE (Integrated Development Environment). You can download it [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).